# Questionnaire Application on Corda

Tags: corda

I am Just learning about Corda. I have seen a couple of tutorials(IOU). Now i was looking to built a simple Questionnaire Application on Corda. I am not able to figure it out where to start with.

Lets say there are 10 Users on the network. One user creates a Questionnaire with 3 questions and now this Questionnaire must be visible to all the other users in the network. Now only 5 users respond to that Questionnaire and submit there response. Now these responses are shared with the user who created that Questionnaire.

What should be the flow and how to write the contract ?
Please help me out here.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sendAndReceive()` (here the [documentation](https://api.corda.net/api/corda-os/4.8/html/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.flows/-flow-session/send-and-receive.html) and a [Cordapp example](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Basic/ping-pong) on github) to send the `Questionnaire` and receive the answer from the participants. Remember that the `SendAndReceive()` expects an answer and if the responder does not reply, the node who started the flow will wait forever. So, the key here is to always send a response back. Up to you to design it as you prefer.